# Is this a shenanigan?

Tags: word-usage

So a guy is making false claims about me online. Can I call it a shenanigan? Would that situation be considered a shenanigan?

Comment: Not really. The word *shenanigans* (which is always a plural) implies something involved, requiring substantial time and effort. Just saying something that someone else disagrees with wouldn't normally be called *shenanigans*.

Comment: The word is used to describe some kind of activity that someone is involved in for some length of time, that requires engagement on their part, that is also silly or illegitimate.

Answer (score 4):

[Shenanigan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shenanigan) is defined as "a devious trick used especially for an underhand purpose." This seems to imply the person is conniving, whereas your situation seems to be a blatant lie, lacking the element of mischievousness.

However, I think it is not completely wrong to call the spreading of false claims shenanigans, as this is obviously a mean act most likely with a malicious intent.

So, if you please, that word can be used, but I do believe there are more fitting words out there.

Comment: I've never heard 'shenanigans' in the singular. Despite MW (a respectable source)'s heading in the singular, all its examples are in the plural form.

Comment: It's very much a (dialectal? regional?) AmE usage that goes back to mid-C19. But [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shenanigan%2Cshenanigans&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshenanigan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshenanigans%3B%2Cc0) suggests that when it started becoming more widespread (as a result of WW2 soldiers interacting with more people from other regions?), there was initially a tendency to "back-form" the non-idiomatic singular usage. But like @Mitch, ***I've*** never heard it used as a singular noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow. There are a lot of singular uses way back. But also, looking at the examples themselves, there are a lot of uses that don't sound like a 'devious tick'. One (repeated) example sounds like a dolly or hand truck.

Comment: @Mitch: After [excluding several repeated instances](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shenanigan%22+-%22no+shenanigan+about+this%22&lr=lang_en&biw=1151&bih=822&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1840%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1917&tbm=bks) in *The American State Reports*, I can only read the singular word in context for nine written instances before the end of WW1. One of those is a 1903 slang dictionary entry, with which all the others seem consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Shenanigans are usually harmless, cause laughter not tears...even if your the victim.
So, not really. If someone is spreading false information about you, it can affects how others see you, or even how you view yourself.